# How to pass a pointer of the inverse array to a funtion?

Tags: c, pointers

Is it possible to make an inversion of `mu` while passing pointer to a function? There is an original function:

```
void norm1(float *F, float *mu, int N, int nav) {
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int bl = i/nav;
    F[i] *= 2*nav / mu[bl];
  }
}
```

I want to have something like this:

```
void norm2(float *F, float *mu, int N, int nav) {
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int bl = i/nav;
    F[i] *= 2*nav * mu[bl];
  }
}
```

Of course, when I call it in that way: `norm2(F, 1/mu, N, nav);` it doesn't work, but i hope you will know what i want to do

Comment: `1/mu` doesn't make sense to me if `mu` is a `float*`. Clarify your question, please.

Comment: Unrelated but you realise your function masks the input variable `bl` when you redeclare it inside the function scope?

Comment: I know, but if it had been a float i would have done it in that way. I ask if there is a way to do it providing it is a `float*`.

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid division, don't -- you'll end up moving the division to where you find the inverse instead of the expression in the loop, but you'll still need it... so you're just adding in unnecessary multiplication without saving anything.

Comment: Do you want the inverse only within the function, or do you want the array modified for the caller (and possibly beyond) as well?

Comment: @Dmitri Agreed, unless the function `norm2` is being called in a loop with the same `mu`.

Comment: Note: `int bl = i/nav;` is suspicious.  1) hides function `bl`m 2) `nav` not declared. 3) Unless `nav == 1` all of `mu` not used.

Comment: @chux, you're right, I've made some mistakes.

Comment: Say `N=100, nav = 1,10 or 30`.  With `nav = 1`, `mu[0] to mu[99]` needed. With `nav = 10`, `mu[0] to mu[9]` needed.  With `nav = 30`, `mu[0] to mu[3]` needed.  So the pre-divide may not need to form all `mu[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
// Allocate an array to hold the inverse of mu
float* mu_inv = malloc(N*sizeof(*mu_inv));

// Compute the inverse of mu and assign it to the newly allocated array.
for ( int i = 0; i < N; ++i )
{
   mu_inv[i] = 1.0f/mu[i];
}

// Call norm2 with the inverse of mu
norm2(F, mu_inv, N, bl);

// Deallocate memory
free(mu_inv);
```

Comment: Will not work, trying to use &mu_inv as an array in norm2 will cause memory violation.

Comment: This is what the OP wanted i guess, but in reality this wont save any time right? You still do the divide which will be the long part, plus now we allocate an array as well. I guess maybe if we call `norm2` in a loop or something with the same `mu_inv` ...

Comment: @Ben, this is one way to get the computation right. Whether the cost of allocating/deallocating memory and computing the inverse is an obstacle is not clear from the OP's question.

Comment: @RSahu I agree, just thought it would be worth mentioning that this wont actually save any time, but it will move the divide from inside to outside the function which answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
@Ben, I use Nvidia's CUDA, dividing on GPU is very inefficient so I'm trying to accelerate it.

Comment: @physicist You will still be doing the divide? is only `norm2` run on the GPU?

Comment: @Ben, yes, only `norm2` runs on GPU and somehow it's faster.